# Odoo 11 Qweb Custom Report : Error to render compiling AST TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python, odoo-11, qweb

My first time publishing something here, hope it will work !

I'm trying to create a custom report in Odoo 11, in a custom module I did, I've followed the data I could gather but I can't get past the following problem.

- So I created the Report like this :

> ```
>       <report 
>           id="production_order_report2"
>           model="pb.orders.products"
>           string="Production Order (English)"
>           report_type="qweb-pdf"
>           name="probespoketest.production_order_report_en2_template"
>           file="probespoketest.production_order_report_en2_template"
>           attachment_use="False"
>       />
> ```

- My Qweb report is :

> ```
>   <template id="production_order_report_en2_template">
>    <t t-call="web.html_container">
>         <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
>             <t t-call="web.internal_layout">
>                 <div class="page">
>                     <h2>Report title</h2>
>                     <p>This object's name is</p>
>                   <t t-esc="testing()"/>
>                 </div>
>             </t>
>         </t>
>     </t>
>       </template>
> ```

- My python code is :

> ```
> from odoo import api, fields, models, _
>
> class OrderProductsFunctions(models.AbstractModel):
>     _name = 'report.probespoketest.production_order_report_en2_template'
>
>     def _testing(self):
>       result = 0
>         return result
> ```

- My error is :

> ```
>  Odoo Server Error
>     Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "/opt/odoo/odoo11/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb/qweb.py", line 342, in _compiled_fn
>         return compiled(self, append, new, options, log)
>       File "<template>", line 1, in template_1454_24554
>       File "<template>", line 2, in body_call_content_24553
>       File "<template>", line 3, in foreach_24552
>       File "<template>", line 4, in body_call_content_24551
>     TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
>
>     During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
>     Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "/opt/odoo/odoo11/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1617, in report_download
>         response = self.report_routes(reportname, docids=docids, converter='pdf')
>       File "/opt/odoo/odoo11/odoo/http.py", line 516, in response_wrap
>         def response_wrap(*args, **kw):
>       File "/opt/odoo/odoo11/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1566, in report_routes
>         pdf = report.with_context(context).render_qweb_pdf(docids, data=data)[0]
>       File "/opt/odoo/odoo11/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_actions_report.py", line 628,
> ```
>
> in render_qweb_pdf
>               html = self.with_context(context).render_qweb_html(res_ids, data=data)[0]
>             File "/opt/odoo/odoo11/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_actions_report.py", line 666,
>   in render_qweb_html
>               return self.render_template(self.report_name, data), 'html'
>             File "/opt/odoo/odoo11/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_actions_report.py", line 470,
>   in render_template
>               return view_obj.render_template(template, values)
>             File "/opt/odoo/odoo11/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 1195, in render_template
>               return self.browse(self.get_view_id(template)).render(values, engine)
>             File "/opt/odoo/odoo11/addons/web_editor/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 27, in
>   render
>               return super(IrUiView, self).render(values=values, engine=engine)
>             File "/opt/odoo/odoo11/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 1204, in render
>               return self.env[engine].render(self.id, qcontext)
>             File "/opt/odoo/odoo11/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb/ir_qweb.py", line 57, in
>   render
>               return super(IrQWeb, self).render(id_or_xml_id, values=values, **context)
>             File "/opt/odoo/odoo11/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb/qweb.py", line 271, in render
>               self.compile(template, options)(self, body.append, values or {})
>             File "/opt/odoo/odoo11/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb/qweb.py", line 349, in _compiled_fn
>               raise QWebException("Error to render compiling AST", e, path, node and etree.tostring(node[0], encoding='unicode'), name)
>           odoo.addons.base.ir.ir_qweb.qweb.QWebException: 'NoneType' object is not callable
>           Traceback (most recent call last):
>             File "/opt/odoo/odoo11/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb/qweb.py", line 342, in _compiled_fn
>               return compiled(self, append, new, options, log)
>             File "", line 1, in template_1454_24554
>             File "", line 2, in body_call_content_24553
>             File "", line 3, in foreach_24552
>             File "", line 4, in body_call_content_24551
>           TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
>
> ```
>     Error to render compiling AST
>     TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
>     Template: 1454
>     Path: /templates/t/t/t/t/div/t
>     Node: <t t-esc="testing()"/>
> ```

**manifest**.py and the two **init**.py should be ok but I can provide the code if needed.

Maybe the problem is that I should call the method testing() adding something. If I try to do :

```
> <t t-esc="docs.testing()"/>
```

Then I get :

```
> Error to render compiling AST AttributeError: 'pb.orders.products' object has no attribute 'testing' Template: 1454 Path:
> /templates/t/t/t/t/div/t Node: <t t-esc="docs.testing()"/>
```

Because my testing method is stored in another module that depends on the one I try to modify. But I don't know how to resolve this...

**=== EDIT ===**

@WaKo

Following your answer I coded this in my models.py (in the module where pb.orders.products is coded, aka "probespokeq") :

```
class OrderProductsFunctions(models.AbstractModel):
    _name = 'report.probespokeq.production_order_report_en2_template'
def _testing(self):
    result = 0
    return result

@api.model
def render_html(self, docids, data=None):
    report_obj = self.env['report']
    report = report_obj._get_report_from_name('probespokeq.production_order_report_en2_template')
    docargs = {
        'doc_ids': docids,
        'doc_model': report.pb.orders.products,
        'docs': self,
        'testing': self._testing,  # You need to add this line
    }
    return report_obj.render('probespokeq.production_order_report_en2_template', docargs)
```

Yet, I still have the same error message. Any idea ?

**===== EDIT 2 ====**

So, now I changed my class according to @WaKo suggestion with `get_report_values` instead of `render_html` so it looks like this :

> ```
> class OrderProductsFunctions(models.AbstractModel):
>     _name = 'report.probespokeq.production_order_report_en2_template'
>
>     def _testing(self):
>         result = 0
>         return result
>
>     @api.multi
>   def get_report_values(self, docids, data=None):
>       docs = self.env['pb.orders.products'].browse(docids)
>       return {
>           'doc_ids': docs.ids,
>           'doc_model': 'pb.orders.products',
>           'docs': docs,
>           'testing': self._testing,  # You need to add this line
>       }
> ```

So, now I change my xml as follows :

```
> <?xml version="1.0"?> <t
> t-name="probespokeq.production_order_report_en2_template">    <t
> t-call="web.html_container">
>         <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
>             <t t-call="web.internal_layout">
>                 <div class="page">
>                     <h2>Report title</h2>
>                     <p>This object's name is probespokeq</p>
>                   <t t-esc="o.testing()"/>
>                 </div>
>             </t>
>         </t>
>     </t>      </t>
```

And I get :

```
> Error to render compiling AST AttributeError: 'pb.orders.products'
> object has no attribute 'testing' Template: 1455 Path:
> /templates/t/t/t/t/div/t Node:  <t t-esc="o.testing()"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use `testing` in you report template like you did you should define it in a [custom report parser](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/reference/reports.html#custom-reports) and add it in `docargs` dict.

```
from odoo import api, models

class ParticularReport(models.AbstractModel):
    _name = 'report.module.report_name'

    def _testing(self):
        result = 0
        return result

    @api.model
    def render_html(self, docids, data=None):
        report_obj = self.env['report']
        report = report_obj._get_report_from_name('module.report_name')
        docargs = {
            'doc_ids': docids,
            'doc_model': report.model,
            'docs': self,
            'testing': self._testing,  # You need to add this line
        }
        return report_obj.render('module.report_name', docargs)
```

You can also define `testing` method in `pb.orders.products` and use `o.testing()` in your template.

You can find an example of a custom report which overwrites [get_report_values](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/11.0/addons/sale/report/sale_report.py#L133) function:

```
@api.multi
def get_report_values(self, docids, data=None):
    docs = self.env['pb.orders.products'].browse(docids)
    return {
        'doc_ids': docs.ids,
        'doc_model': 'pb.orders.products',
        'docs': docs,
        'testing': self._testing,  # You need to add this line
    }
```

**Examples**

To use a method from your model:

```
class PBOrdersProducts(models.Model):
    _name = "pb.orders.products"

    name = fields.Char()

    def testing(self):
        result = 0
        return result
```

And use:

```
<t t-esc="o.testing()"/>
```

In the template.

To use a custom parser like they did in `sale` module:

```
class ParticularReport(models.AbstractModel):
    _name = 'report.test.production_order_report'

    def _testing(self):
        result = 0
        return result

    @api.multi
    def get_report_values(self, docids, data=None):
        docs = self.env['pb.orders.products'].browse(docids)
        return {
            'doc_ids': docs.ids,
            'doc_model': 'pb.orders.products',
            'docs': docs,
            'testing': self._testing,  # You need to add this line
        }
```

And in this case you will need to use:

```
<t t-esc="testing()"/>
```

Comment: I edited my post according to your advice. Might I still be able to enquirer your help, please?

Comment: Use `get_report_values` instead of `render_html` and tell me what happened.

Comment: Did you use try the second `function` and added in the template file `<t t-esc="testing()"/>`to use it ?

Comment: Yes (I re edited the post). I tried with both  <t t-esc="testing()"/> and <t t-esc="o.testing()"/>
Sorry for the bothering and thanks for the help !

Comment: It's OK, Check my edit after `Examples`.I tested both methods and they worked.

Comment: OK, I found I have another problem that doesn't allow me to upgrade my module so I can't test your solution. But thanks a lot ! 
I posted my new problem here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51857231/odoo-11-upgrade-module-indexerror-list-index-out-of-range